# Windows 8/RT App Crash Report - How to analyze it?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windbg, crash-dumps, cab

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong in my Windows Store App? I have [this crash dump file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/73i5771j5zg9q8r/crashdumpfile.cab).

One of the problems is that the error never occurs on my PC, but only on some user PCs/tablets. Another problem is, that I really don't know the error. I tired opening with WinDdg and I ran `!analyze -v` but I am not getting any smarter with this problem.

Could you give me any help, any hint how to proceed with this problem? I would really like to work on the problem, but I don't understand the problem...

Comment: can you share a full dump (not a mini)?

Comment: No, as I said I cannot reproduce the error. And the dump above is the only one, which is available form the Developer Dashboard. Sorry...

Comment: without a full dump we can't see anything.

Comment: The dropbox link is broken...